# error_description="Invalid token" in oracle apex push notification

Tags: push-notification, oracle-apex, progressive-web-apps

In Oracle Apex pwa push notification (version 23) when calling:

```
apex_230100.wwv_flow_pwa.push_queue_immediate(p_force_yn =\> 'y');
```

we got below error

```
HTTP/1.1 401 UnauthorizedContent-Length: 0X-WNS-MSG-ID: 2561D3717258F6FAX-WNS-DEBUG-TRACE: AM3PEPF0000624EMS-CV: eR1j/f/eFkSNJCiEO4O2sQ.0Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomainsWWW-Authenticate: bearer error="invalid_request",error_description="Invalid token"Date: Mon, 16 Oct 2023 14:13:01 GMTConnection: close
```

Also we set windows notification CA in my database wallet (MicrosoftRSRootCertificateAuthority2017.crt)

Our Oracle database is in Iran; is the windows notification banned for Iranian developers? or is my certificate is invalid?